# Erro no Eclipse usando o servidor TomCat 9.0 Tomcat - Erro 404

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlet

Estou tentando rodar um site web usando Servlet TomCat9,onde o usuário ira digitar o salário dele, e de acordo com a faixa salarial ira ser feito um reajuste nesse salário antigo!
A linguagem usada é JAVA

Criei os Pacotes Beans e Web ,os quais foram pedidos pelo professor,criei também o arquivo html!
Minha página HTML está rodando normal,porem na hora de enviar os dados,para que esses possam ser "pegos" e assim feito os cálculos me aparece o seguinte erro:

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found : The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

E eu realmente não sei o que fazer para concertar isso,já vi tutoriais que dizem para mudar o local do servidor - fiz e não mudou em nada.
Então peço ajuda para conseguir resolver o erro! Estou mandando também meus códigos HTML,O código Bens e o WEB!

> 6. Crie uma Servlet que recebe o salário de um colaborador e o reajuste segundo o
>      seguinte critério, baseado no salário atual:
>      a. salários até R$ 280,00 (incluindo): aumento de 20%
>      b. salários entre R$ 280,00 e R$ 700,00: aumento de 15%
>      c. salários entre R$ 700,00 e R$ 1500,00: aumento de 10%
>      d. salários de R$ 1500,00 em diante: aumento de 5%

```js
CÓDIGO BEANS

package br.com.fiap.com.web;

public class Salario {
 
 private double salario;

 public Salario() {
  super();
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

 public Salario(double salario) {
  super();
  this.salario = salario;
 }

 public double getSalario() {
  return salario;
 }

 public void setSalario(double salario) {
  this.salario = salario;
 }
       
 public double  
 elseSalario (double salario ){
  
  if(salario <= 280.00) {
   salario = salario * 0.20;
  }
  else if(salario > 280.00 && salario < 700.00) {
   salario = salario * 0.15;
  }
  else if(salario > 700.00 && salario < 1500.00) {
   salario = salario * 0.10;
  }
  else if(salario > 1500.00) {
   salario = salario * 0.05;
}
  return salario; 
  }
 
 public double  
 calculaPorcentagem (double salario ){
  
  if(salario <= 280.00) {
   salario = salario * 0.20;
  }
  else if(salario > 280.00 && salario < 700.00) {
   salario = salario * 0.15;
  }
  else if(salario > 700.00 && salario < 1500.00) {
   salario = salario * 0.10;
  }
  else if(salario > 1500.00) {
   salario = salario * 0.05;
}
  return salario; 
 }
}



CÒDIGO WEB

package br.com.fiap.nac.beans;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import br.com.fiap.com.web.Salario;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/salario")
public class CalcSalario extends HttpServlet {
 @Override
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
 
  PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
  
  writer.println("<html><body>");
  writer.println("Seu Salário foi Reajustado");
  
  
  Salario salario = new Salario();
  salario.setSalario(Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("Salario")));
  writer.println("<p>"+salario.elseSalario(salario.getSalario())+"</p>"); 
  
  
}
  
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Salário</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Vamos calcular seu novo salário?</h2>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Dados:</legend>
    <form action="recebe" method="get">
    <label for="salario"><b>Salário:</b></label>
    <input type="text" id="idsalario" name="seusalario"
    placeholder="Digite o seu salário"/>
    <button>Enviar</button>
    </form>
</fieldset>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Um palpite, pois não testei o código: no servlet está `urlPatterns="/salario"` e no html está `form action="recebe"`. O action deve enviar para a URL do servlet ("/salario"). Como ele está enviando para uma URL que provavelmente não existe ("recebe"), dá erro 404. E depois que arrumar isso: no servlet você faz `req.getParameter("Salario")`, mas o nome do campo no html é `name="seusalario"`, ou seja, o servlet está tentando pegar um nome de campo que não existe no html, então também vai dar erro. Isso é o que vi numa primeira olhada, como não testei pode ser que tenha mais coisas pra mudar...

Comment: hkotsubo então onde eu devo arrumar? no url ou no meu form action?

Comment: pois se eu mudo o urlPatterns="/salario" para  / recebe ele continua com erro ,mesmo eu mudando o getParameter para seusalario

Comment: Fiz um teste aqui, coloquei `urlPatterns = "/recebe"` e `form action="recebe"` e funcionou.  Criei um web project no eclipse do zero, com as duas classes e o html e não precisei fazer mais nada. Você tentou acessar a URL diretamente só pra ver se está ok? `http://servidor/nomeaplicacao/recebe`. Talvez seja algum detalhe de configuração faltando, não sei...

Comment: obrigada pela ajuda!